# How can I stop my page from loading to another HTML and give error alert instead?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to stop my HTML page loading onto another HTML page that gives me an error, instead, I would like it to show in an alert dialog.

```js
function Download() {
   location.href = "ModifiedIndex/"+document.getElementById("refID").value+".zip";

   if(location.href == null) {
     alert (document.getElementById("refID").value + ".zip" + "does not 
      exist!")
   }
}
```

```html
<h3>Enter FileName # to start download...</h2>
<input type="text" id="refID" title="Enter FileName # to start download">
<button onclick="Download()">Download</button>
```

Comment: You set `location.href` to a string on line one of the function, and then on line three in the `if` statement you test to see if it `null` - doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: location.href will never be null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you update `location.href` the browser will already start going to that page so anything after that line of code is more or less irrelevant.  You can't stop a page from loading if you're already going to it.  You should check that the file exists first, and then redirect accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
async function Download() {
  let url="ModifiedIndex/" + refID.value + ".zip";

  try {
    let r = await fetch(url, { method: 'HEAD'});
    location = url;
  } catch(e) {
    alert(refID.value + ".zip does not exist!")
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Enter FileName # to start download...</h2>
<input type="text" id="refID" title="Enter FileName # to start download">
<button onclick="Download()">Download</button>
```

Comment: @JasonAller thanks for advice: use 'HEAD' to reduce traffic :) - very smart - I update answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the file exits, you have to use ajax.

```
    <h3>Enter FileName # to start download...</h2>
    <input type="text" id="refID" title="Enter FileName # to start download">
    <a href="#" id="click" download>Download</a>

    function input() {

        let input = document.getElementById("refID");

        let value = input.value;

        if (! value) {

          alert('The Input is empty');

          return false;
        }

       return value;
   }

   let click = document.getElementById("click");

   click.onclick = function (e) {

      if (input()) {

          let file = `${input()}.zip`;

         this.href = `${input()}.zip`;
      }
 };
```